# Can't seem to concatenate multiple files in different directories

Tags: command-line, find, io-redirection, cat

I'm trying to concatenate multiple files together that are in different directories using the following command:

```
~$ find . -name ‘*.text’ -exec cat {} >> combined.text \;
```

However it doesn't seem to be working as I am getting a response as:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Is there something that I have may missed?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a typo. You are missing `+` (or `\;`, which would be less efficient)  after `{}`.  You also seem to have typographical single quotes (`‘` rather than `'`) in the argument to `-name`.  Unless you really want to _append_ to your output file with the command, change the `>>` to `>`.

Comment: I have included the `\;` after the `{}` but it doesn't seem to work. How am I able to make if efficiently work?

Comment: Also fix the single quotes that I mentioned. Use `+` instead of `\;` to run `cat` as few times as possible.  The redirection should still come last on the command line (it's the output of the `find` command you are redirecting, as a whole).

Comment: What's the advantage of `find` here over `cat *.text >> combined.text`?

Comment: @Panki Well, they have files in multiple subdirectories, and `cat *.text` would furthermore fail if there are too many files.

Comment: It seems even with `+` it doesn't seems to view any of the subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using unicode quotes: `‘’` instead of normal quotes (`''`). Try this command instead:

```
find . -name '*.text' -exec cat {} +  >> combined.text
```

However, if `combined.text` already exists, that will print a warning since `combined.text` will be created before launching `find` so will be found by the `find` command:

```
$ find . -name '*.text' -exec cat {} +  >> combined.text
cat: ./combined.text: input file is output file
```

You can avoid that with:

```
find . -name '*.text' ! -name combined.text -exec cat {} + >> combined.text
```

Comment: Hi, an  irrelevant question : I thought `{}` must be in the end before `+`, but `{}` in your command doesn't, while it still works, what am i missing?

Comment: @dedowsdi the `+` or the `\;` must be at the very end of the command you give to `-exec`: `find ... -exec command +`. So if the command includes a redirection, you need the `+` before: `-exec cat {} >> file +`. However, `find ... -exec cat {} + > file.txt` will also work, but because here you are redirecting the output of the entire `find` command. So `find` will `cat` the files and then print to standard output and you are using the normal shell redirection to save the output of `find` to a file. In this particular case there isn't much difference, really.

Comment: The `>>` redirects `find`, not `cat`. The file will therefore be created before `find` is actually invoked (not when `cat` is run).  This is as it should be.  Just move the `>>combined.txt` to after the `\;` or `+` to avoid confusion.  Would you want to redirect `cat` specifically, you would need to do so with `-exec sh -c 'cat "$1" >>combined.text' sh {} \;`, or `-exec sh -c 'for file do cat "$file"; done >>combined.txt' sh {} +`, or something similar (but that's a bit silly).

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah, I don't really know why I did it the other way originally. I blame a lack of coffee.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The may still want to explicitly exclude the output file, or use a different filename suffix...  After you've had that coffee, of course ;-)

Comment: @Kusalananda d'oh! And I'm all caffeinated now, no excuse!

Comment: This seem to work! Thank you everyone!!!